# Does any one have experienced with Java SWT browser component what do you think?

Tags: java, browser, swt

Hi 
i need to use embed browse , found this swt wrapper , what do you think?
can i use it as my browser control does any one have experienced with it ?
it need to support MAC and Linux laso...

Answer (score 0):

The question is what you would like to accomplish? I've used the swt wrapper in the past to create a cross platform "flash player". Goal was to show flash files under win/mac/linux and have full control over the window/size/position. For this purpose it works well.

Comment: i need cross platform browser component

Comment: understand that ... but what is the goal? Do you want to program a competitive browser? For this purpose I wouldn't use the component (not enough control). Or do you just want to show some websites inside your application? For this the component is powerful enough. You can test it out if you install eclipse. Open the view "Internal Web Browser". This view uses the swt wrapper and demonstrates what it is capable of.

Comment: i need to capture the http response that caming from the http request im doing from the browser , from reading i see i can't do it with SWT wrapper or am i wrong ?